# How can i do: Intent(this, FMXNativeActivity.class); without importing FMXNativeActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

in the manifest i have :

```
    <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity" ... >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="me.myFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and myFirebaseMessagingService is inside a dedicated jar

now the problem is that from myFirebaseMessagingService i want to launch an activity via intent. normally i must do like this :

```
import com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FMXNativeActivity.class);
```

however from inside the jar i don't have access to the code of FMXNativeActivity (because the jar is to be used in a generic way).

How can i do? can i set the activity name inside the `<service ..></service>` as params ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an action for your activity in manifest and start the activity from service using that action.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity" ... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

In your service,

```
String CUSTOM_ACTION = "com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION";
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);
startActivity(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver that starts your service and when you want to invoke the service simply broadcast with appropriate action this way your broadcast receiver can start the service